# How to take these labels in exactly required position

Tags: java, jframe, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to create a small GUI with some lables and txtAreas. I did it by using absolute positioning, but I want to go on gridbag layout. I am trying from last 3 days, but couldnt get these lables as required position. either stucking in the middle around, or they stucking near the border. Please help to get them in these positions.

public void initUIPanel()
    {

```
    jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setTitle("Mortgage Calculator");
    jf.setLocation(100,200);
    jf.setSize(400,500);
    jf.setVisible (true);
    //jf.setResizable(false);



JPanel panel = new JPanel();
GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

loanAmount = new JTextField(15);
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(loanAmount, gbc);
panel.add(loanAmount);


loanTerm = new JTextField(15);
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(loanTerm, gbc);
panel.add(loanTerm);


amount = new JLabel("Loan Amount");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(amount, gbc);
panel.add(amount);


term= new JLabel("Loan Term");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(term, gbc);
panel.add(term);


currency = new JLabel ("AUD");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(currency, gbc);
panel.add(currency);


numOfYear = new JLabel ("Year");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(numOfYear, gbc);
panel.add(numOfYear);


JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel ();

middlePanel.setBorder ( new TitledBorder ( new EtchedBorder (), "Display Area" ) ); 
txtResult = new JTextArea();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbl.setConstraints(txtResult, gbc);
panel.add(txtResult);


jf.add(panel,"Center");
//panel.setBounds(200,200,200,20);
jf.setVisible(true);

}
```

It is giving everything in 2 lines. all messed. 
What I want is

```
First Line: Loan Amount: ............(txt Area).... "AUD"
Second LIne: Loan Term: .............(Txt Area......Years
```

Then Txtbox

Thank you

Comment: Your code doesn't use the gridbaglayout at all. Show us the code that you tried, and tell us what you would like the panel to look like, and how it actually looks like.

Comment: I have edited my post. Please have a look. thanks

Comment: All your components have gridx and gridy set to 0, so they all share the same cell in the grid.

Comment: sorry for this. But even changing any of them donot change the position in GUI. thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the layout of the panel:

```
panel.setLayout(gbl);
```

And, as already said in the comments, all the components have the same gridx and gridy, which is obviously not right.

Here's a complete example which, if I understand correctly, does what you want:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GblTest extends JFrame {

    public GblTest() {
        add(createPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_LEADING;
        p.add(new JLabel("Loan amount"), c);

        c.gridx++;
        p.add(new JTextField(15), c);

        c.gridx++;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        p.add(new JLabel("AUD"), c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy++;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        p.add(new JLabel("Loan term"), c);

        c.gridx++;
        p.add(new JTextField(15), c);

        c.gridx++;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        p.add(new JLabel("Years"), c);

        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GblTest test = new GblTest();
                test.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                test.pack();
                test.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What I want is "loan Amount" label is to be placed nearby the north/west corner. But its just roaming around the center. I tried by placing the panel in "North", but then its hanging in the center of the north.

Comment: See my edited answer. You must tell some cell to enlarge horizontally in order for the panel to be aligned to the left.

Comment: Thank You Nizet. I had never seen such clear example. Even my tutor couldnt explain it as you just did. I am grateful for your help.